# Android Parse SDK don't works with self signed SSL

Tags: java, android, ssl, parse-server, self-signed

I'm trying to use Parse SDK in my project in Android Studio to make user authorization. It worked while the my parse server was http. Now the server use https and I can't use Parse. When I try use `logInInBackground()` I get error `i/o failure`.

Certificate is self sign and it works on PHP, JS and iOS. But fails on Android.
Parse SDK works in my project if server don't use SSL, but I need solve problem with `https`.

Answer (score -1):

Parse has been shut down and is not recommended to be used. Shift to Firebase which has User Authorization and other features like Realtime database

Firebase Auth: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: Please, provide some reference for that.

Comment: Hosted Parse.com was shut down but made open source, and is plenty recommended to be used.